# laravel how to parse compact variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
@foreach($brand as $br)
{{$br->brands}}
@endforeach
```

i echo out my variable like this and i get this output

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Eurboor","description":null,"status":1,"slug":"eurboor","icon":null,"sort":0,"pivot":{"product_category_id":4,"brand_id":1}}] [] [{"id":2,"title":"Aquasol","description":null,"status":1,"slug":"aquasol","icon":null,"sort":0,"pivot":{"product_category_id":6,"brand_id":2}}] [{"id":1,"title":"Eurboor","description":null,"status":1,"slug":"eurboor","icon":null,"sort":0,"pivot":{"product_category_id":7,"brand_id":1}}] [{"id":1,"title":"Eurboor","description":null,"status":1,"slug":"eurboor","icon":null,"sort":0,"pivot":{"product_category_id":8,"brand_id":1}}] [{"id":5,"title":"D.W.T","description":null,"status":1,"slug":"dwt","icon":null,"sort":0,"pivot":{"product_category_id":9,"brand_id":5}}] [{"id":3,"title":"Steel Weld","description":null,"status":1,"slug":"steel-weld","icon":null,"sort":0,"pivot":{"product_category_id":10,"brand_id":3}}]
```

So how do i get "brand_id" or something else i tried $br->brands->brand_id or similar thing but it didnt work pls help me out :(

/////////////////////Update

```
@foreach($brand as $br)
@foreach($br->brands as $singlebrand)
{{$singlebrand->id}}
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

This worked for me ty :)

Comment: `$br->brands` is another array (note then `[]` surrounding the json), so you have to iterate through that.

Comment: It is better to answer your own question and accept iti instead of updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

The brand_id is stored in your pivot table, to access it, you could go:

```
$br->pivot->brand_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This
$br->pivot->brand_id

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($brand as $br)
@foreach($br->brands as $singlebrand)
{{$singlebrand->id}}
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

This worked